# RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' - when subtracting two DataFrames of floats

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames of floats of shapes (940, 1682). The majority of elements in the both are zero, and any non-zero elements are in the exact same positions in both. I am attempting to find their element-wise differences.

When executing

```
diff = df1 - df2
```

I get the above error and `diff` is a (940, 1682) DataFrame of `NaN`s.

To investigate, I attempted the following:

```
print("1")

for i in range(df1.shape[1]):
    diff = df1.iloc[0, i] - df2.iloc[0, i]
    if type(diff).__name__ != 'float64':
        print(i)

print("2")

diff = df1.iloc[0] - df2.iloc[0]

print("3")
```

which outputs:

```
1
2
/home/kevin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3772: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)
3
```

In other words, it is able to calculate the subtraction one element at a time, but when I attempt to do the entire row at once, it throws the warning.

What does this error mean in this case, and how can I find the source of it?

I can provide download links to the two DataFrames if they are needed.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
You should be able to provide a suitably small test set that provokes the problem.

Comment: You seem to be subtracting a column named 0 from df2 from the first row of df1 between print(''2'') and print(''3'')...

Comment: @xyzjayne Sorry, that was just a typo when copying and pasting the code and changing the variable names.

Comment: Can you check df1.dtype and df2.dtype and paste it in your question? This error suggests that you have string rather than float somewhere.

Comment: @xyzjayne But then the error would still occur in the loop between 1 and 2, wouldn't it?

Comment: Sometimes (and I haven't figured out what times), elementwise operations won't raise errors as it would for columnwise operations... My suggestion would be actually printing the values of ````diff```` if the type is not what you are expecting in your for loop.

Comment: @xyzjayne See my edited code - nothing was ever printed within that loop. Is this what you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes - that's super weird. Have you checked if the two dataframes have the identical column labels? The error is about '<' rather than subtraction itself so it might be related to pandas trying to figure out what to do with column labels that don't match

Comment: I noticed hours ago that they have different column labels but I didn't think it would make a difference. `df1`s labels are 1-1682 and `df2`s are 0-1681. I will reset `df1`s. Why does this matter?

Comment: Because pandas performs subtraction for identically labeled elements (as opposed to based on position). Take an extreme case where you have a 1x1 df with index named 1 and column named 'a', and another with index named 0 and column named 'aa'. When you subtract the two, you'll get a 4x4 df with index/column labels from both dfs and all entries NaN.